# Continue fine-tuning from saved checkpoints for run_language_modeling.py

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I followed the isntructions to fine-tune the pretrained BERT model with a customized corpus, as shown here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/language-modeling. During the process of training, there are checkpoints generated under the specified output_dir, however, when I wanted to continue training from one of the checkpoints (--model_name_or_path=/path-to-ckpt/), it returns the traceback that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_language_modeling.py", line 277, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_language_modeling.py", line 186, in main
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_args.model_name_or_path, cache_dir=model_args.cache_dir)
  File "H:\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_auto.py", line 203, in from_pretrained
    return tokenizer_class_py.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
  File "H:\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils.py", line 902, in from_pretrained
    return cls._from_pretrained(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "H:\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils.py", line 1007, in _from_pretrained
    list(cls.vocab_files_names.values()),
OSError: Model name 'C:\\path-to-ckpt\\checkpoint-17500' was not found in tokenizers model name list (bert-base-uncased, bert-large-uncased, bert-base-cased, bert-large-cased, bert-base-multilingual-uncased, bert-base-multilingual-cased, bert-base-chinese, bert-base-german-cased, bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking, bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking, bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad, bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad, bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc, bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased, bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased, bert-base-finnish-cased-v1, bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1, bert-base-dutch-cased). We assumed 'C:\\path-to-ckpt\\checkpoint-17500' was a path, a model identifier, or url to a directory containing vocabulary files named ['vocab.txt'] but couldn't find such vocabulary files at this path or url.
```

As I comprehend, there is a mismatch between the files saved in the checkpoint directory and the files needed to load the model, furthermore, it could also be that there is no explicit argument to specify continue training from checkpoints. However, I am not sure whether I complicated things or there is alternative way to do so.